# Change Dropbox User in Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on an application where I need to use DropBox ,I am using DropBox 1st time ,Using android DropBox API I authenticate successfully , But when I try to change already authenticated user its saying an error as > Invalid User
"Only a limited set of users can receive access tokens while this app is in development mode".
Anyone can guide what's the reason of this error message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is indicating that your app is in development mode, meaning you can only link the account that registered it:

[Dropbox - Core concepts](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/core)

If you're not ready to apply for production, but need to test with additional users, see here:

[Test your apps with up to five users](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/13)